# Use quicksilver to tell iTunes to stop

Tags: mac, quicksilver

I am starting to use Quicksilver in Mac OS X. At the moment I just know how to "call it" (CMD+I in my case) and open an app. I wonder how could I do, once iTunes is running, just to tell to stop playing a song, using QS, and if not, someother workaround, just using Keyboard, in the simplest possible wy.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It you have the iTunes module installed and enabled it gives you several control scripts.  I use the Play-Pause script and my abbreviation for it is "pp".    The Next Song script is also handy.

Comment: hi,

i installed the itunes module in quicsilver. where can i access to the keys for activating it? thanks

Comment: @user10826 - Call up Quicksilver and the type in the abbreviation for the application, command, script, etc. that you wish to run. In this case try typing stop or pp or something similar and choosing from the list so it knows what action to use when you enter that string of characters.